# How to set multiple properties for Maven on Teamcity

Tags: maven, teamcity, maven-release-plugin

The configuration passes a property to Maven using the "Additional Maven command line parameters" setting for the Maven runner.
This is done with `-Darguments=''` so the `maven-release-plugin` can use the arguments on each run as it forks new processes.

For one property the configuration is:

```
-DsomeProp=%teamcity.agent.name% -Darguments='-DimportantProp=true'
```

The problem is when passing multiple properties like so:

```
-DsomeProp=%teamcity.agent.name% -Darguments='-DimportantProp=true -DsecondProp=file_on_disk.name'
```

For the multiple properties configuration the Build log shows that `importantProp` gets resolved as `true -Dsecondprop=file_on_disk.name` which is expectedly an invalid value.
The second property `secondProp` is then not applied as the string gets absorbed into the value of `importantProp`.

The reason to do this is to simplify test runs on TeamCity and not to change the poms for each test.
I see hardly any examples for this configuration on TeamCity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a configuration parameter to the configuration twice has worked. Thanks for the configuration parmeter suggestion Senior Pomidor.

Create configuration parameter in build parameters or build template `%mavenArguments%`:

```
-DpropCheck=true -DpropPath=file_on_disk-1.path
```

Then apply the supplied configuration parameter in the `Additional Maven command line parameters` on the Maven build step (works directly on the build step or through build template) like this:

```
%mavenArguments%
-Darguments='%mavenArguments%'
```

I still have no idea why it's not applied correctly by writing directly into the `Additional Maven command line parameters` but it finally works.

Answer (score 1):

your props differ by  `-DsecondProp=true`. So, you should create only one prop for a pass to build. Let's name `mainProp`

Also, we need to add new prop which contains empty if not checked or `-DsecondProp=true` if checked. Create checkbox parameter `additionalParam` with

- checked value  - `-DsecondProp=true`
- unchecked value  - `` (nothing)

Now we need to add this cb parameter our mainProp. 
`mainProp = -DsomeProp=%teamcity.agent.name% -Darguments='-DimportantProp=true %additionalParam%'`

When you will triggered the build you can check the checkbox and pass `-DsomeProp=%teamcity.agent.name% -Darguments='-DimportantProp=true -DsecondProp=true`

Comment: I'll give it a test, but if I'm not mistaken it looks like it would generate the same string being passed to maven in the end. I clarified the example a bit to show that the second parameter is actually a file name.

Comment: I tried to pass a parameter as I said in the answer and it passed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, it has helped in making a working solution. I will post the complete changes in an answer.